# How to press 1(numpad) in textbox1 but show 2 on textbox1

Tags: vb.net

I have textbox1. And i need to press some numeric in textbox1.

ex.press 1 in textbox1 but value in textbox1 is 2(not random).
press 1 show 2
press 2 show 3
.
.

Comment: You just need to catch the keypress event and set the value you want on pressing 1/2/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the control:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "1"
            TextBox1.AppendText("2")
        Case "2"
            TextBox1.AppendText("3")
    End Select

    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

If you want to restrict input to JUST the Numeric Keypad (but not the number row), use the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    Select e.KeyData
        Case Keys.NumPad1
            TextBox1.AppendText("2")
        Case Keys.NumPad2
            TextBox1.AppendText("3")
    End Select

    e.Handled = True
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could i ask you e-mail or facebook for directory enquiries.

Comment: @Ich-LiebeDich, sorry I can't do that.  Please post your questions on SO for the benefit of all to see.